# finite integral of $\frac{1}{|x|^s}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Here follows first the question and after what I've managed to work out

Question: Let $r>0$ and consider the ball $B(0,r)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the integral $\int_{B(0,r)}\frac{1}{|x|^s}\,dx$ is finite if and only if $s<n$.

What I've done: $$\int_{B(0,r)}\frac{1}{|x|^s}\,dx=|\partial B(0,r)|\int_0^r\frac{1}{|x|^s}|x|^{n-1}\,dx=|\partial B(0,r)|\int_0^r|x|^{n-1-s}\,dx$$
$$=|\partial B(0,r)|\cdot\left[\frac{x|x|^{n-1-s}}{n-s}\right]^{x=r}_{x=0}=|\partial B(0,r)|\cdot\frac{r^{n-2}}{n-s}$$

From this point I don't know how to continue. Also, my knowledge of multivariable calculus isn't that great, so I'm not familiar with most techniques, so I might've also made some fundamental mistakes in my attempt. If there's other things possible than my approach, please also let me know. (context: This question is asked during the studying of the Fundamental Solution of the Laplace Equation from PDE.)

Comment: Please, use MathJax also in the title.

Comment: indeed i thought it was a floor in the title!

Comment: fixed it, forgot I could do that in the title too!

Comment: You could simplify the problem a little by taking $r=1$, which is obviously equivalent to the general case.

Comment: I did realize that, but even then, I couldn't really see how to get the desired result. I see that $n=s$ is an issue, but what goes wrong when $s>n$?

Comment: At some point you changed a vector integral to a real integral. I suggest you don't use the same symbol ($x$) to denote both a vector and a real number. That should make the calculations clearer so you can realize what's happening.

Comment: so from the first $=$ onwards I should replace the $x$ with, say, a $y$? Also, I'm not too sure what I used in that step, hence the perhaps strange notation. I wrote it on paper earlier using some identity for integrals over balls I believe. But didn't I use a line-integral here? (I have never used these before, but some Wikipedia told me that I believe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a consequence of the [Coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) we have that

\begin{align*}
\int_{B_r(0)}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\lVert x\rVert^s}
&=\int_0^r\int_{\partial B_R(0)}\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(x)}{\lVert x\rVert^s}~\mathrm{d}R \\
&=\int_0^r\frac{\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial B_R(0))}{R^s}~\mathrm{d}R \\
&=\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial B_1(0))\int_0^r \frac{R^{n-1}}{R^s}~\mathrm{d}R \\
&=\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial B_1(0))\int_0^r \frac{\mathrm{d}R}{R^{s-n+1}},
\end{align*}

where $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ denotes $(n-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. $(n-1)$-dimensional volume in $\mathbb{R}^n$). The resulting integral converges if and only if $s-n+1<1$, i.e. if and only if $s<n$ as desired.

---

If you're curious about its exact value when it converges, then we know from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) that

$$\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial B_1(0))=\frac{2\pi^ {n/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)},$$

where $\Gamma$ denotes the Gamma function, so

$$\int_{B_r(0)}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\lVert x\rVert^s}=\frac{2\pi^ {n/2}r^{n-s}}{(n-s)\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}.$$

Comment: thanks! The only part I don't get is why the integral only converges when $s-n+1<1$, why does this follow from the above?

Comment: @JackpotWizard180 It's a standard result from one variable calculus that $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^a}$ converges if and only if $a<1$. Indeed if $a=1$, then we get $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow0}\left(\ln(1)-\ln(\varepsilon)\right)=\infty$ and if $a>1$ then we get $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^a}=\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow0}\left(1-\frac{1}{\varepsilon^{a-1}}\right)=\infty$. Does this make sense?

Comment: That does makes sense, I've just never seen this result in either our Calculus nor our Analysis classes before, thanks for the further elaboration, I get it now!